# Python: converting tuple into 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I want to convert tuple like

```
t = [(4,10),(9,7),(11,2),(2,2)]
```

into 2D array like:

```
a = [[4,10],[9,7],[11,2],[2,2]]
```

I tried

```
a = []
for i in t:  
    a.append(np.asarray(i))
print a
```

is there any easier way?

Comment: `a = map(list, t)` Py2 , `map` changes in Py3 and you need `a = list(map(list, t))` for Py3

Comment: @AChampion As OP is using Python 2.7, I think there is no need to cast the `map()`result to a list.

Comment: Thanks, I was in the process of fixing - I work almost exclusively in 3 now so tend to forget these anachronisms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) comprehension as follows:

```
>>> t = [(4,10),(9,7),(11,2),(2,2)]
>>> [list(item) for item in t]
[[4, 10], [9, 7], [11, 2], [2, 2]]
```